# Is there a function or method to use voice response (say) in twilio inside the streaming function?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-click-to-call

```
def call():
    """Accept a phone call."""
    global response
    start = Start()
    start.stream(url=f'wss://{request.host}/stream')
    response.append(start)
    response.say('Please leave a message')
    response.pause(length=60)
```

I want to able to use response.say inside stream function

```
def stream(ws):
    global response
    response.say("Hi")
```

I tried to run with the above code but it didn't work anyway although it didn't show any errors at run time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need a way to use twilio for automated voice responsing when streaming some input from someone while talking.